# Conditions for optimal stopping time

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, optimal-control

According to C. Evans' book *Introduction to stochastic differential equations*,
we consider the following control problem:

Let $U\subset R^{m}$ be a bounded, smooth domain. Suppose $b: R^{n} \longrightarrow R^{n}$, $B: R^{n}\longrightarrow M^{n.m}$ has usual assumptions

Then for $x\in U$ the stochastic differential equation:

$$dX=b(X)dt+B(X)dW.$$

$$X_{o}=x.$$

has a unique solution. Let $\tau_{x}$ denote the hitting time of $\partial U$. Let $\theta$ be any stopping time with respect to $F(\cdot)$, and for each such $\theta$ define the expected cost of stopping $X(\cdot)$ at time $\theta \wedge \tau$ to be

$$J_{x}(\theta) = E\left(\int_{0}^{\theta \wedge \tau} f(X(s))ds+g(X(\theta \wedge \tau))\right).$$

We consider the value function

$u(x)=\inf_{\theta} J_{x}(\theta)$.

Then optimality conditions:

Assuming that $u$ is smooth enough then we can prove:

1) Let $\theta=0$, we get $u(x) \leq g(x)$.

2) At $x\in \partial U$, $u(x)=g(x)$.

3) $0\leq f(x)+Lu(x)$, where $L$ is infinitesimal generator of $X(t)$ (also elliptic operator).

The problem is that I don't know why $0=f(x)+Lu(x)$ for $x$ satisfies $u(x)<g(x)$.

Comment: I have just found out a way how to prove it.

Because it cannot stop at the first time, we get

$g(x)\geq E(\int_{0}^{\delta} f(X(s))ds)+Eg(X(\delta))$ (1).

Using Ito's formular for g, we have $Eg(X(\delta))=g(x)+E\int_{0}^{\delta}Lg(X(s))ds$. Substituting this formular into (1) we can get$ f(x)+Lg(x) \leq 0.$

Hence, $f(x)+Lu+L(g-u) \leq 0$, but we have $f(x)+Lu \geq 0$ so if $f(x)+Lu>0$ then $L(g-u)<0$. So, there is a neighbood U of x such that $g(y)<u(y)$ for all $y\in U$. [Contradiction-we always have $g(x)\geq u(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in U$ be such that $u(x) \lt g(x)$. Recall that, by point 3 of your question, $f(x) + Lu(x) \ge 0$. 
Suppose that $\tau$ is the first stopping time minimizing $J_x(\theta)$, i.e.,
$$ u(x) = \mathbb{E}\int_0^{\tau} f(X(s)) \, ds + \mathbb{E}\, g(X(\tau)). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Then it follows that 
$$ \mathbb{E}[g(X(\tau))] = \mathbb{E} [u(X(\tau))].$$
Indeed, suppose that it is not true, then $\mathbb{E}[g(X(\tau))] > \mathbb{E} [u(X(\tau))]$ and, by Itô's formula for stopping times,
$$ \mathbb{E}[g(X(\tau))] > \mathbb{E} [u(X(\tau))] = u(x) + \mathbb{E} \int_0^\tau Lu(X(s)) \, ds,$$
that is, by eq. \eqref{1}, 
$$ \mathbb{E} \int_0^\tau \left( Lu(X(s)) + f(X(s)) \right) ds < 0, $$
a contradiction.

Now,
$$ u(x) = \mathbb{E} \int_0^\tau f(X(s)) \, ds + \mathbb{E} \, u(X(\tau)), $$
and, again by Itô's formula, 
$$ \mathbb{E} \int_0^\tau \left( f(X(s)) + Lu(X(s)) \right) ds =0. $$
Recall that $Lu+f \ge 0$ and, hence, $Lu(x) + f(x) = 0$ as claimed.